# squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth on Android

Tags: java, sonarqube

This is my setup:

- SonarQube 5.6.6
- SonarJava plugin 4.8.0.9441

Code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends android.app.Activity {}

public class FooActivity extends BaseActivity {}
```

SonarQube thinks that `FooActivity` violates `squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth`:

> This class has 6 parents which is greater than 5 authorized.

`android.app.Activity` is Android Native API.
Shouldn't any super classes of `Activity` be ignored when calculating violations for this rule?

**Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, but rather a configuration issue. Rule [`squid:S110`](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-110) can be configured to filter out classes from the inheritance tree. By default, no class is ignored and the rule simply count the number of inheritance levels till reaching `Object` class. In order to configure filtered classes, you have to set up the `filteredClasses` rule property.

Note that it is plan to update to rule to not simply exclude filtered classes from the total inheritance depth, but stop incrementing inheritance levels as soon as reaching a filtered class. The fix will be done when handling Jira ticket [SONARJAVA-2252](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2252).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to "set up the filteredClasses rule property", specifically in the context of Android?

Comment: I configured the rule for the Quality Profile to set filteredClasses to: android.app.*,android.view.*,android.content.*,android.os.*

Comment: Update: I also added the support library versions (v4, v7, etc)

Comment: Update 2: With Androidx you now also need to add the appcompat package version(s)

Comment: Link squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth  is broken, please fix @michael?

Comment: @JacquesKoorts fixed. Rule key changed, it's now S110: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-110

Comment: @Alix Please share the filteredClasses that you have used for Android

Comment: @sunil this is my current config: "android.app.*,android.view.*,android.content.*,android.os.*,android.support.v7.app.*,android.support.v4.app.*, android.arch.lifecycle.*, androidx.appcompat.app.*"

Answer (score 0):

you can anytime suppress this warning by using below annotation at class level
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth")

Comment: Please read questions carefully. OP clearly asked for: "Is this a bug?" - Besides that you should never suppress any error messages, notices or warnings.