# Sonarqube error : This class has 10 parents which is greater than 5 authorized

Tags: android, sonarqube

Getting this error in MainActivity activity. In which class should be the issue? In MainActivity itself or other classes called from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654193/squidmaximuminheritancedepth-on-android

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The sonarqube check is too tight for Android.

Comment: Checked the link but don't know how to set filteredClass property